# UserWarning: No contour levels found within the data range

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone explain what does the Python compiler mean when it says:

`UserWarning: No contour levels found within the data range` ?

I couldn't find any good resources on the web about the mentioned `UserWarning`. Thanks in advance for the help!

PS: I am trying to implement a paper related to image segmentation and I am using `matplotlib` library for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/ucar.edu/g/wrfpython-talk/c/0NWrmA4hBwA) answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check it out.

Comment: this question should be marked as a *duplicate* of the linked question instead. please take the [tour]